# grep current directory only

Tags: grep

I would like to search all the files in the current directory only. I tried this

```
grep foo *
```

but I get this error

```
grep: bar: Is a directory
```

I also tried this

```
grep -r foo
```

but this is searching subdirectories as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your version of `grep`, you may be able to write:

```
grep --directories=skip foo *
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a comment, just don't have enough reputation to place it as a comment.
your 1st answer is actually correct.

if bar is a directory within the same directory you want to search files and you don't like the error.
It can also be simple just to do away with error.
e.g.
 grep foo * 2> /dev/null